# Probability with or and under in the questions

Tags: probability

Can anyone please help me to solve these problem with explanation as possible.

[image]

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag and read its wiki https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study and then tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Please the the [help/on-topic] in relation to homework-style questions. If you can't show a serious attempt that we can help you with, you will need to ask a very specific question about some aspect of it.